# Cutting out a section of HTML without using regex?

Tags: javascript, html-parsing

I am trying to remove a section from some HTML. Here is an example of what I am working with (some of the specific div id's might change, but the idea is here):

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<div dir="ltr">---------- Forwarded message ---------<br>data data data<br></div><br><br>
<div id="itemID" style="margin:0px"><div style="margin:0px">
<html i want to keep etc>
```

I want to transform this so it looks like:

```
<div id="itemID" style="margin:0px"><div style="margin:0px">
<html i want to keep etc>
```

And as another example, this HTML:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<div dir="headerline">---------- Forwarded message ---------<br>data data data<br></div><br><br>
<div id="itemID2" style="margin:10px"><div style="margin:10px">
<html i want to keep etc>
```

Should be transformed to look like this:

```
<div id="itemID2" style="margin:10px"><div style="margin:10px">
<html i want to keep etc>
```

In other words, look for `Forwarded message` in the first or second line and, if you find it, delete every line up to and including that one. Right now the working RegEx looks like this:

```
var HTMLbodynew = HTMLbody.replace(/\n.+Forwarded Message.+\n/,"");
```

However, as described in a notorious Stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), I shouldn't be using regex to parse HTML. Is there a way to accomplish this without regex?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

```
document.querySelector("div[dir='ltr']").remove();

for (const brElement of document.querySelectorAll("br")) {
    brElement.remove();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately not every HTML document this needs to work on has the "ltr" (also, some of the divs in the html I want to keep later have "ltr"). I have updated the question to try to make this more clear.